# How can put a dispute over Stripe transaction

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

Is there any api in stripe so that customers can generate a dispute. I see a submit evidence api :

```
    stripe.disputes.update("dp_17sGETLpSdVJN1iVw8BHvseP",
    {
        evidence: {
        customer_email_address: 'email@example.com',
         shipping_date: '2016-06-08',
         shipping_documentation: 'file_17sapWLpSdVJN1iV0X1yRT8Z'
     }
  },
  function(err, dispute) {
     // asynchronously called
  });
```

what is "dp_17sGETLpSdVJN1iVw8BHvseP" in this api and from where is it obtained

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There isn't option to create dispute using the API. The dispute created by the user when customers questions your charge with their bank or credit card company.

After the user create dispute you can respond by providing evidence.

> A dispute occurs when a customer questions your charge with their bank
>   or credit card company. When a customer disputes your charge, you're
>   given the opportunity to respond to the dispute with evidence that
>   shows the charge is legitimate.
>
> https://stripe.com/docs/api#disputes

**More info**:

[Stripe disputeS FAQ](https://stripe.com/docs/disputes/faq)